# GCP dashboard Query editor

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dashboard, stackdriver, mql

I have a dashboard created from stackdriver custom log metrics.
My question is how can I show only one split stack bar for 1 day.
This is the query in query editor:

```
fetch gae_app 
| metric 'some-custom-metric' 
| filter (metric.log == 'appengiene-log') 
| group_by 1d, 
    [value_new_aggregate: 
       aggregate(value.new)] 
| every 1d 
| group_by [label1:metric.label1a, label2:ascii_to_upper(metric.label2a)],
    [value_new_aggregate_aggregate: aggregate(value_new_aggregate)]
```

this displays the dashboard chart as below for a day:
[image]

but I want to display it like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For my kubernetes cluster CPU allocatable utilization below MQL gives me the stacked bar like this[image] which I believe similar like yours

```
fetch k8s_node
| metric 'kubernetes.io/node/cpu/allocatable_utilization'
| filter resource.project_id == 'xxxxxxxxxx'
| group_by 1d,
    [value_allocatable_utilization_aggregate:
       aggregate(value.allocatable_utilization)]
| every 1d
| group_by [resource.cluster_name],
    [value_allocatable_utilization_aggregate_aggregate:
       aggregate(value_allocatable_utilization_aggregate)]
```

Comment: not sure why its not working in my case. The main reason for using Query editor is to use ascii_to_upper(), which is not supported in basic/advanced metric.

Comment: Was the answer useful to solve your issue? If so, can you accept it

Comment: Regarding the 1st image (Green/orange query), are you showing the visualization period per week instead of per day? that's not visible and in the 2nd image the time frame was selected per 1D or by 1W? I cannot see it neither, finally and as 3rd option what if you add in addition to ```ever 1d``` + ```align rate``` too



also checkout [how to configure dashboard widgets](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts#configure-widget)

Comment: ```| align rate(1d)```

```| every 1d```

note that there is a line break between both fields, not sure 100% if this will solve your issue but let me know